# express.static not working. Cant get images

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So, I am trying to access images from my uploads folder but getting following error:
[image]

I have added `express.static(root, [options])` to my **server.js** here is the source code.

```
require("dotenv").config({
  path: "C:/Users/dogra/Documents/Web Development/Portfolio/FullStack/market/.env",
});
const path = require("path");
const express = require("express");
const connectDB = require("./config/db");
connectDB();
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

// Express Static Middleware
const staticPath = path.join(__dirname, "../uploads");
app.use(express.static(staticPath));

// Routes
const productRoutes = require("./routes/productRoutes");
const userRoutes = require("./routes/userRoutes");
const orderRoutes = require("./routes/orderRoutes");
const uploadRoutes = require("./routes/uploadRoutes");

app.use("/api", productRoutes);
app.use("/api/users", userRoutes);
app.use("/api/orders", orderRoutes);
app.use("/api/upload", uploadRoutes);

app.get("/api/config/paypal", (req, res) =>
  res.send(process.env.PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID)
);

// uploads to "/uploads" folder
app.use("/uploads", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/uploads")));

// Check's If the route is not defined and passes 404 error
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const error = new Error(`Requested URL: ${req.path} not found!`);
  error.status = 404;
  next(error);
});

// Error handler
app.use((error, req, res, next) => {
  res.status(error.status || 500);
  res.json({
    error: {
      success: false,
      status: error.status || 500,
      message: error.message,
    },
  });
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(
  PORT,
  console.log(`Server running in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} on port ${PORT}`)
);
```

My file directory looks like this:
[image]

Also, I console.log `staticPath` it is pointing to right directory. What I am doing wrong? Please Help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove your first `app.use(express.static` as that's wrong.  But your `app.use("/uploads",` looks good.

Comment: why do you use the static twice ? Have you tried `app.use("/uploads", express.static(staticPath))

Comment: oops, I must have forgotten that I have added it. Anywhich wase both are not working

Comment: I have Updated the question Sorry from my part.

Comment: Yes, you was nearly there with your second one, as pointed out by @SilvanBregy answer your uploads is up a directory, so you just need to put `../uploads` on your "path.join"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your path is still pointing to the wrong file. Log the path and see by yourself:

```
console.log('static path:', path.join(__dirname, "/uploads"))
```

So you have to write `path.join(__dirname, "../uploads"))` since `__dirname` will resolve to the `./server` directory.

You did that in the lines above but i guess the second call of `express.static()` has overwritten the `uploads` static path.

So this should work:

```
app.use('/uploads', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../uploads'));
```

Maybe you want to use `process.cwd()`. It always points to the location the program is started, so if you start your program via `npm start` then `process.cwd()` will always point to the directory the `package.json` is located!

Comment: Well spotted, the uploads is up a directory.  I would say the `path.join(__dirname, "../uploads"))` is actually better than `process.cwd()` as that can change, even during runtime.

Comment: @Keith The path won't change at runtime because the static path is only registered at startup? or am i wrong?. I suggested `process.cwd()` because if at some day the `server.js`  file may change location then the code still works. But that's my opinion..

Comment: Yes, it won't change any existing routes you have created.  But let's say you ran a routine that changed the working directory before you setup the routes, or a shortcut that had an incorrect working directory.  Or instead of doing `node index` you did `node myprogram/index`.   In some circumstances this may indeed be what you want to happen, eg. if you use the npm serve, it's logical it runs from cwd.  So in the end, it's just something to be aware of more than anything.

Comment: @Keith As i said. When running using `npm start`.. paths change, opinions change.. 
I am happy to use process.cwd() as it also works in , call it "compiled" environments like when using `pkg` or `nexe`.  But everyone has it's own preferences.

Comment: Yes, if it works for you that's fine.  Like I said it's just something to be aware of.  I've been bitten before using `cwd`, so I always like the none movable `__dirname`, but like you say personal preference.